# ajax response return with function for

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

Can you tell me how can I replace code html with function 'for from django'?

```
$.ajax({                                                                                                                           
    url: url,
    data: $('#FormSite').serialize(), 
    type: "POST",
    async:false,
    success: function(response) {
        $($("#Pic").first()).replaceWith($(response['Pic']));
        $("#HeaderWpis").text(response['h1']);
        $("#WpisChild").html("<div id='WpisChild'> {% for News in Messags %} <p>{{ News.title }}</p> </div>");
    },
    error: function(data)
    {
        alert('Bad connection');
        console.log(data);
    }

});
```

When I do this I got {%for%} from third div 'WpisChild' as text. The function does not perform on the page. Could you tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

The Django template language is processed when your views are accessed, so JQuery can't interpret it. Here are two suggestions:

1. Create the HTML with the Django template language by using the render() function in your views.py file. You will need to create a new template with that HTML segment and direct the AJAX call to a new view. The Messages would be passed to the template as the context and the {% for %} loop will work. The response will be the fully constructed HTML which you can then .append() to the chosen div.

```
def get_messages(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # do whatever with your request, fetch your messages

        context = {
            'Messages': messages
        }
        return render(request, 'message-template.html', context)
```

```
$("#WpisChild").append(response)
```

2. Include the Messages data in your existing response, loop through the list and append each one as an element to the div. This option might be preferred if your response has other data.

```
response['Messages'].forEach(function(news) {
    $("#WpisChild").append('<p>' + news.title + '</p>')
});
```

Comment: Hi, I have to add that I'm using (jsonresponse) because ajax just changes only the appropriate divs downloaded from .txt. I hope that you understand me. Second solutions I think it will be solved this, but Can I do this with jsonrespone?

Comment: Yes that shouldn't be a problem, it's not too different to the way that you're already using the response

Comment: But I need reloaded csrftoken or somthing? I meant that I don't want to use the second solution and I want to paste {{News.title}} as django code. Can I do this or I have to use separate functions in js or py?

Comment: If you want to use the Django template language (i.e. {{ News.title }}) and not use the second option then you would need to change the rest of your AJAX call (the response['Pic'] and response['h1'] parts). These look like HTML elements so I would suggest creating all three elements in a single template, render it through your views.py file, request it via AJAX and append it to the div.

Comment: Okey but it will be change without refreshing site? Could you get me some simple example? :)

Comment: It's still an AJAX request so won't refresh the page. The template might look something like this (I'm not sure what your variables are called) - the view would look like the code in my original post:
`<div id='Pic'>{{ Pic }}</div>
<div id='HeaderWpis''{{ h1 }}</div>
<div id='WpisChild'>
{% for News in Messags %}
  <p>{{ News.title }}</p> 
{% endfor %}
</div>`
Then your JQuery would look something like:
`$(container).clear()
$(container).append(response)`

Comment: Ajax code I do that same, but my py look:    `if request.is_ajax and request.method == "POST": Messages = NewsMessage.objects.all().order_by('-Data').values()
        context = {
            "Messags" : Messages
        }
        return render(request, 'example.html', context)` and example.html its `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<div>
    HAHAHAHAH LOLA
</div>` and it's not work. Ajax result success but nothing change.

Comment: Your example.html isn't using any Django template language, remove the <HTML> tags (as you're inserting this into the existing HTML page) and change the <div> to be wrapped by the template language `{% for message in Messags %} <div> {{ message.title }} </div> {% endfor %}`

Comment: Everthing fine. I change in js code: `$("container").replaceWith(response);` and now it's work. I have only problem with `UrlCut = request.GET['site']` it's don't wan take value from ?site in url. Before with .txt it worked.